# PyMongo max_time_ms

Tags: python, mongodb, timeout, locking, pymongo

I would like to use the max_time_ms flag during a find on mongodb, but I woulld like to understand how this flag works and how to verify that it is working.

```
pymongo find().max_time_ms(500)
```

Is there any way to verify?
I tried to `db.fsyncLock()`, but I get this is applicable only for inserts.

I thought that a possible solution should be insert too many entries and reduce to `max_time_ms(1)`, so the query will not have enough time to take results.

Any suggestions?
Tks

Answer (score 3):

Passing the `max_time_ms` option this way

```
cursor = db.collection.find().max_time_ms(1)
```

or

```
cursor = db.collection.find(max_time_ms=1)
```

sets a time limit for the query and errors out with a `pymongo.errors.ExecutionTimeout` exception when the time limit specified is exceeded for the query.

Since cursors are lazy, this exception is raised when accessing results from the cursor *e.g.*

```
for doc in cursor:
    print(doc)

ExecutionTimeout: operation exceeded time limit
```

> `max_time_ms` (optional): Specifies a time limit for a query
>               operation. If the specified time is exceeded, the operation will be
>               aborted and :exc:`~pymongo.errors.ExecutionTimeout` is raised. Pass
>               this as an alternative to calling
>   [[Source: Docs]](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/3.6.0/pymongo/collection.py#L1320)

Comment: For search’s sake, `import pymongo.errors.ExecutionTimeout` is what you need to prevent `NameError: name 'ExecutionTimeout' is not defined` when trying to catch on `ExecutionTimeout`.