# How to abort mongo operation after given time limit using the pymongo MongoClient constructor?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

According to [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48839121/955422) you can set a time limit for a query operation via find() parameter or a collection method:

```py
cursor = db.collection.find(max_time_ms=1)
```

or

```py
cursor = db.collection.find().max_time_ms(1)
```

The [doc](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) says:

> - *max_time_ms* (optional): Specifies a time limit for a query operation. If the specified time is exceeded, the operation will be aborted and ExecutionTimeout is raised. Pass this as an alternative to calling max_time_ms() on the cursor.

We're currently experiencing a problem that a query runs for ~30 minutes before it eats all the RAM and the server dies. I hope this parameter gives a hard limit on the query and after the given time the server gives up.

Since our app is full of `find`s and cursors: **is there a way how to set this parameter directly in the `MongoClient` constructor?**

The [doc](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html) says:

> - *socketTimeoutMS*: (integer or None) Controls how long (in milliseconds) the driver will wait for a response after sending an ordinary (non-monitoring) database operation before concluding that a network error has occurred. Defaults to None (no timeout).
> - *connectTimeoutMS*: (integer or None) Controls how long (in milliseconds) the driver will wait during server monitoring when connecting a new socket to a server before concluding the server is unavailable. Defaults to 20000 (20 seconds).
> - *serverSelectionTimeoutMS*: (integer) Controls how long (in milliseconds) the driver will wait to find an available, appropriate server to carry out a database operation; while it is waiting, multiple server monitoring operations may be carried out, each controlled by connectTimeoutMS. Defaults to 30000 (30 seconds).

...couldn't find another timeout and none of these seem to be the equivalent of `max_time_ms`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think all these timeouts for drivers only, not for server side. To kill process in server use [db.killOp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/)

Comment: It's currently not possible but there is a feature request for this: [SERVER-13775](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13775)